# ffmpeg and exr - unsupported channel ZBack

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a sequence of exrs generated by a Maya render to a quicktime movie.  I am running ffmpeg on Windows 7 (64 bit).  However, my quicktime is coming out black.

```
>ffmpeg.exe -y -i path_to_frames\Render_Beauty.%04d.exr -codec copy -c:v qtrle path_to_frames\Render_Beauty.mov
ffmpeg version N-66673-gf0d1b3a Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Oct  6 2014 22:10:42 with gcc 4.9.1 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54.  9.100 / 54.  9.100
  libavcodec     56.  3.101 / 56.  3.101
  libavformat    56.  7.104 / 56.  7.104
  libavdevice    56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
  libavfilter     5.  1.102 /  5.  1.102
  libswscale      3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  1.100 / 53.  1.100
[exr @ 000000000037f680] Unsupported channel ZBack.
[exr @ 000000000037f680] decode_block() failed.
    Last message repeated 1079 times
Input #0, image2, from 'path_to_frames\\Render_Beauty.%04d.exr':
  Duration: 00:00:03.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: exr, rgba64le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25
tbn, 25 tbc
path_frames\\Render_Beauty.mov:
 No such file or directory
```

I think the issue has something to do with the ZBack channel in the exrs:

```
[exr @ 000000000037f680] Unsupported channel ZBack.
[exr @ 000000000037f680] decode_block() failed.
```

I tried the conversion with a later version of ffmpeg (20170921 - 183fd30), but ended up with an entirely different error message:

```
[exr @ 000000000032b120] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[image2 @ 00000000003286c0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 00000000003286c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video:
 exr, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
```

Any hints on how to solve this?

=====Update=====

Weird.  I ran an updated version of ffmpeg against some test files (like I did earlier) and got some new error messages.

```
C:\Users\spearsc\Desktop\test_files>R:\_tools\ffmpeg_g183fd30\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -
i Test_Beauty.%04d.exr -codec copy -c:v qtrle Test_Beauty.mov
ffmpeg version N-87353-g183fd30 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --e
nable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --
enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv
--enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-li
bfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug -
-enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enabl
e-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolam
e --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx
 --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable
-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      55. 76.100 / 55. 76.100
  libavcodec     57.106.101 / 57.106.101
  libavformat    57. 82.101 / 57. 82.101
  libavdevice    57.  8.101 / 57.  8.101
  libavfilter     6.105.100 /  6.105.100
  libswscale      4.  7.103 /  4.  7.103
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[exr @ 00000000005da8c0] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[image2 @ 00000000005d7fe0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 00000000005d7fe0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video:
 exr, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, image2, from 'Test_Beauty.%04d.exr':
  Duration: 00:00:00.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: exr, none, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (exr (native) -> qtrle (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] flags 8 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version
to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file
 has a feature which has not been implemented.
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] Error while decoding stream #0:0: Not yet implemented i
n FFmpeg, patches welcome
    Last message repeated 1 times1 times
[exr @ 0000000007bf1a40] Error while decoding stream #0:0: Not yet implemented i
n FFmpeg, patches welcome
 is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If t
he problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not bee
n implemented.
    Last message repeated 6 times
Finishing stream 0:0 without any data written to it.
Nothing was written into output file 0 (Test_Beauty.mov), b
ecause at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0k
bits/s speed=N/A
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing ove
rhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters i
f used)
Conversion failed!
```

Setting the probesize and analyzeduration does not seem to really help.

```
>R:\_tools\ffmpeg_g183fd30\bin\ffmpeg.exe -y -probesize 100M -analyzeduration 100M -i Test_Beauty.%04d.exr -codec copy -c:v qtrle Test_Beauty.mov
```

Comment: Your ffmpeg is old and is currently behind by at least 21,120 commits. I don't know if a new version will help in this case but it is always the first step. For Windows get a new ffmpeg at https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: Doesn't look to be supported yet.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am afraid of.